# Laravel API timeout

Tags: laravel, api, server, ftp, timeout

I have a website made with laravel 7. I have a problem that the website is smoothly accessed but the FTP hosting and API often timeouts

I tried switching to a new server provider and the result was that the website, FTP, and API had no problems. But the old provider said it wasn't a server problem

Comment: So how do you want us to help you? I don't see a question and I don't see code.

Comment: My question is why did that happen. Is the constraint on the server or something else. Because my code runs smoothly on another server provider

Comment: Nobody knows man, there is not enough info